# ubuntu back on google drive is too large

Tags: backup, drive, google

I created a backup for my ubuntu desktop I used my google drive for backup. I don't have any files on my system but the backup has take 5GB of space on my drive. is that how backup works? as I know backup should only use space if I have files on my pc.

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to what release of Ubuntu Desktop you're using, thus how are we to know?  Ubuntu Desktop recommends a minimum disk space of 25GB which allows for some expansion, but 5GB seems *small* to me for the system (ie. *everything*), but I don't know what release, nor what tool/backup options you selected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.